# Exponential of Matrix Rewritten as Hyperbolic Functions

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, exponential-function, matrix-equations, hyperbolic-functions

Working through a paper and cannot seem to confirm the following equality:

$\exp(-\beta\hbar\omega_i\hat{S_{iz}}) = \cosh(\frac{\beta\hbar\omega_i}{2})-2\hat{S_{iz}}\sinh(\frac{\beta\hbar\omega_i}{2})$

where

$\exp(-\beta\hbar\omega_i\hat{S_{iz}}) = \exp(-\beta\hbar(\omega_1\hat{S_{1z}}+\omega_2\hat{S_{2z}}))$,

$\hat{S_{1z}} = \begin{matrix} 
1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1/2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1/2  
\end{matrix}$

and

$\hat{S_{2z}} = \begin{matrix} 
1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1/2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1/2  
\end{matrix}$

Any help/resources would be appreciated. My main concern is how the matrix moves in front of the hyperbolic sin function and out of the argument.

Comment: In fact, all involved matrices are diagonal, thus you need to work only component by component because in particular $exp(diag(a,b,c,d))=diag(exp(a),exp(b),exp(c),exp(d))$. Besides the RHS of the first formula should be $\color{red}{I_4}\cosh(\frac{\beta\hbar\omega_i}{2})-2\hat{S_{iz}}\sinh(\frac{\beta\hbar\omega_i}{2})$.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand the property of exponentials of diagonal matrices. I still do not see how this moves the matrices outside of the argument of the hyperbolic functions

Comment: What are the different $\omega_k$s ? Numbers or $2 \times 2$ Pauli matrices ? In the second case I wouldn't understand how a $4 \times 4$ matrix is multiplied by a $2 \times 2$ matrix...

Comment: ... (ctd) unless it is a $4 \times 4$ representation of Pauli matrices...

Comment: These are just numbers, sorry for not clarifying that.